# JavaScript Code Required to Generate an Ethereum Address?

Tags: wallets, addresses, javascript, paper-wallets

I am aware of several tools and websites that generate addresses for you, but I'm looking for an actual JavaScript code snippet to demonstrate the steps plainly.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Take a look at :

https://github.com/kvhnuke/etherwallet

( and mainly, this file, search for generateSingleWallet : https://github.com/kvhnuke/etherwallet/blob/gh-pages/js/source/01_global.js )

It is the source code for the https://www.myetherwallet.com/ that provides in-browser generation of ethereum addresses.

A simple javascript snippet (using CryptoJS and staticJS/01_ethereumjs-accounts.js libraries from the forementioned repository):

```
function generateSingleWallet(password) {
  // reference from staticJS/01_ethereumjs-accounts.js
  var acc = new Accounts();
  var newAccountEnc = acc.new(password);
  var addressHash =   
    cryptoJSToHex(CryptoJS.SHA3(newAccountEnc.address));
  addressHash = addressHash.substr(addressHash.length - 4);

  var newAccountUnEnc = acc.get(newAccountEnc.address, password);
  // now: newAccountUnEnc.private is unencoded private key
  newAccountEnc.private = newAccountEnc.private + addressHash;
  // now: newAccountEnc.private is encoded private key

  // always clear the Accounts object after generation
  acc.clear();
}
```